# Make migrations on heroku is not reflected on the table content. All tables are empty

Tags: python, django, heroku, hosting

I have hosted my app on heroku and it has two tables with 1000 rows but running the code:

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

is migrating only the tables and not the contents. How do I migrate the tables contents?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean, "migrating the contents"? Where is the data supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands `makemigrations` and `migrate` are commands used for handling the database scheme, not the actual data in the database.

You should think of migrations as a version control system for your database schema. `makemigrations` is responsible for packaging up your model changes into individual migration files - analogous to commits - and `migrate` is responsible for applying those to your database.

In short, running both the commands just creates the tables required for your django application. The data has to be populated manually or exported from your development environment and imported in your heroku app. I suggest you read more about django before posting anymore questions.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question.....Is there any way I can transfer my table contents from my Django Admin in my localhost to heroku.....or is it possible only through PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 0):

You should manually create custom migration file with [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) from `django.db.migrations.operations` (see [examples here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython)). You can do with data any changes you need to update data from the current state to required.
After commit, push to Heroku and run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. This should execute your migration on the remote database.